# Mass of an anti-symmetric spin-1 field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism

I was wondering how does one calculate the mass of an anti-symmetric spin-1 field. For a vector field one writes $m^{2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}$ for mass term. How does one write the mass for "any" anti-symmetric spin-1 field $D_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: What do you mean by antisymmetric?

Comment: $D_{\mu\nu} = -D_{\nu\mu}$

Comment: Right but $A_\mu A^\nu$ is symmetric not antisymettric

Comment: I said "any" anti-symmetric spin-1 field.

Comment: I see what you're asking now hah.. Thought that you were saying something else..